# detect changes in the System.Windows.Forms.TabPage

Tags: asp.net, winforms, tabcontrol

I have a System.Windows.Forms.TabControl with collection of System.Windows.Forms.TabPage. Each TabPage is a form where users can enter text values. When a user changes tab, If there are any changes in the current tab; I need to prompt them if they want to save changes made in the current tab. How do I detect if there was a change in the state of current TabPage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach an event handler to each control on the tab page, which sets a flag to indicate that data on the tab page has been changed ("is dirty").

Subsequently, attach an event handler to the `Selecting` event of your `TabControl` to show a prompt when you detect that the dirty flag has been set to `true` for the tab page that is about to be navigated away from.